# Programmatically list all attributes from xmlns

Tags: java, android, xml

given the namespace:

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

I want to list all possible attributes (eg. `android:id`, `android:layout_width`, etc) and store in a hashmap ("id", "layout_width", "layout_height", etc).

Is there a way to do that? Where do IDEs grab those attributes to suggest them?

Thanks.